# Start Activity from non activity class/project

Tags: java, android-intent, android-activity, 2d-games

I've been developing a game for android but it is very important to know that I didn't use a single Activity until now. My game is working quite good until now but I want to make use of one activity for some settings because this is way more easy to change.. I've been reading some similar topics but I didn't succeed in my purpose yet. So i need to get an intent to the SettingsActivity coming from a tap on the screen in bounds of 5,5,75,75 as you see in the code.. As I said I've been reading some similar topics and use the code but it didn't work.. Thanks for helping

```
public class MainMenuScreen extends Screen  {


    public MainMenuScreen(Game game) {
        super(game);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();

        List<TouchEvent> touchEvents = game.getInput().getTouchEvents();

        int len = touchEvents.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
            if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {



                    if(inBounds(event,5,5,75,75)){

                        // Get an Intent to open the SettingsActivity


                    }if(inBounds(event,85,350,200,75)){

                        System.out.println("Start Last level");
                        if(SampleGame.progress==0)
                        Settings.currentLevel=0;

                        if(SampleGame.progress==1)
                            Settings.currentLevel=1;

                        if(SampleGame.progress==2)
                            Settings.currentLevel=2;

                        if(SampleGame.progress==3)
                            Settings.currentLevel=3;
                        if(SampleGame.progress==4)
                            Settings.currentLevel=4;

                        Settings.save(game.getFileIO());
                        GameScreen.state=GameState.Ready;

                        game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
                    }if(inBounds(event,500,350,275,75)){

                        game.setScreen(new LevelSelectionScreen(game));

                    }



                }



            }



    }

    private boolean inBounds(TouchEvent event, int x, int y, int width,
            int height) {
        if (event.x > x && event.x < x + width - 1 && event.y > y
                && event.y < y + height - 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(float deltaTime) {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(Assets.menu, 0, 0);



    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    @Override
    public void backButton() {
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

    }
}
```

Comment: Curiosity: Why aren't you using Activities?

Comment: at first I was following a tutorial about game making.. He didn't use activities so  neither do I now... And I have to say, it works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code I can see you are following the book `Beginning Android Games`. This method (single activity with "screens") indeed works great for game development.

If you do want to add extra activities it would be best to implement their starting/handling inside the `Game` (`AndroidGame`) class, which implements the main activity.

In order to do this you could add a `newActivity` method inside this (in the same place as the `setScreen` methods). It's parameters can vary depending on what you need: you could pass an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) directly, or you could pass a [Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html) instead. It all depends on how much freedom you want when re-using the framework.

Here is an basic example of what you can add:

```
public abstract class AndroidGame extends Activity implements Game {

   public void newActivity(Intent intent)  {
      startActivity( intent ); 
   }

   public void newActivity(Class<?> cls)  {
      startActivity( new Intent( this, cls ) );
   }
}
```

These are just two ways to achieve your goal, and they are both very basic. Have a look at the [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) documentation for the various ways in which you can launch activities. Additionally, if you want to receive info back from the activity you can use [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) and implement [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) in the `Game` class as well (maybe with the option to store the last result so it can be processed by your game.